# Lag time adding product to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have an external PHP script that offers up to three of my products listed as `$producturl[x]` from my WooCommerce store. I created an `add to cart` button that triggers a link to add the selected product to the user's cart but it often takes awhile for it to process. I know the process isn't exactly instant but is my code a reason it is acting slow? It often takes 30 seconds or more to pop the alert message saying the product was added. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

**PHP**

```
<div class="buybutton">
    <?php $producturl = ProductURL::find(array('Product'=>$specialty1->Specialty1));
    if($producturl[0]->URL!=NULL){
        echo '<span id="add"><a id="add-link" href="' . $producturl[0]->URL . '" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="d" target="vspage" onclick="' . "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Buy Now', 'Specialty', '" . $specialty1->Specialty1 . "'" . "]); _gaq.push(['_link', '" . $producturl[0]->URL . "']);" . '">';
        if($producturl[0]->Button!=NULL){
            echo $producturl[0]->Button . '</a></span>';
        }else {
            echo 'Add To Cart</a>';
        }
    }
    if($producturl[0]->URL2!=NULL){
        echo '<span id="add"><a id="add2-link" href="' . $producturl[0]->URL2 . '" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="d" target="vspage" onclick="' . "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Buy Now', 'Specialty', '" . $specialty1->Specialty1 . "'" . "]); _gaq.push(['_link', '" . $producturl[0]->URL2 . "']);" . '">';
        if($producturl[0]->Button2!=NULL){
            echo $producturl[0]->Button2 . '</a></span>';
        }else {
            echo 'Add To Cart</a>';
        }
    }
    if($producturl[0]->URL3!=NULL){
        echo '<span id="add"><a id="add3-link" href="' . $producturl[0]->URL3 . '" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="d" target="vspage" onclick="' . "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Buy Now', 'Specialty', '" . $specialty1->Specialty1 . "'" . "]); _gaq.push(['_link', '" . $producturl[0]->URL3 . "']);" . '">';
        if($producturl[0]->Button3!=NULL){
            echo $producturl[0]->Button3 . '</a></span>';
        }else {
            echo 'Add To Cart</a>';
        }
    }
    ?></div>
```

**Javascript in my PHP file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a#add-link').click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault(); 
var url = $(this).attr("href");
$.post(url, function () {
alert("You added this product to your cart.");
});

});

$('a#add2-link').click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault(); 
var url = $(this).attr("href");
$.post(url, function () {
alert("You added this product to your cart.");
});

});

$('a#add3-link').click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault(); 
var url = $(this).attr("href");
$.post(url, function () {
alert("You added this product to your cart.");
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: So if you click the button, you trigger an action on another server with another site/database on it?-

Comment: We need to see what the code is of whatever the url that you are posting to is.

Comment: @RobinR It is my same server just on a subdomain. This subdomain is a wordpress site with woocommerce, so my product links are: http://shop.domain.com/cart/?add-to-cart=683

Comment: @Kyle there really is no code, i copy-pasted the woocommerce link that adds the product to cart. that url is $producturl